# Is this shirk anyone please answer please

Tags: shirk

Assalamualaikum I am given a speech on environmental day which has a line that nature is the gift of nature godness
I know this are wrong and I don't believe in this I have no other option only to say this because I am the host of the program and all the script are written and given by teacher
As I am scared I told my parents about the issue but they beaten me for refusing my chance . please answer is it shirk or not please please

Comment: Please answer this , I know it's bad to say that but it's fixed and I have to do the program

Answer (score 1):

It is shirk to say this sentence while meaning that it is true. The author of this sentence commits/commited shirk. It may be allowable to say this as a citation if it is really necessary.

I wonder why you should hold a speech without having any influence on what you say. Why don't you just alter the text and say that nature is the gift of God?